# Entity Framework Optional One To One Relationship Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, one-to-one

I have alot of entity. One of them `OrderLine` entity use a few relations. It 's relation to `AccountTransaction`. When I get `AccountTransaction` class from context I can get `OrderLine` record with lazy load. But  when I get `OrderLine` class from context `AccountTransaction` navigation property is null.
How can I solve this problem?

```
public partial class OrderLine : Base
{

    [Key, ForeignKey("AccountTransaction")]
    public int OrderLineId { get; set; }

    public virtual AccountTransaction AccountTransaction { get; set; }
}

public class AccountTransaction
{
    [Key]
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrderLine")]
    public int? OrderLineId { get; set; }

    public virtual OrderLine OrderLine { get; set; }        
}


var orderLine = context.OrderLines.Find(167069);
var accTransaction = context.AccountTransactions.Find(38770);


//orderLine.AccountTransaction; //here account transaction is null
//accTransaction.OrderLine;//here orderLine is not null.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing `[ForeignKey]`. It is used to specify the key field for a relationship from the child record, which in this case would be the `AccountTransaction`. Try changing your model to the following:

```
public partial class OrderLine : Base
{

    [Key]
    public int OrderLineId { get; set; }

    public virtual AccountTransaction AccountTransaction { get; set; }
}

public class AccountTransaction
{
    [Key]
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }

    [Index(IsUnique=true)]
    public int? OrderLineId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrderLineId")]
    public virtual OrderLine OrderLine { get; set; }        
}
```

Let me know if it works or if you run into other issues. :)

Comment: i've tried but i raise this exception. AccountTransaction_OrderLine_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'AccountTransaction_OrderLine_Source' in relationship 'AccountTransaction_OrderLine'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'

Comment: Right, because this structure doesn't follow a normal 1:1 pattern, but a 1:many. Try adding `[Index(IsUnique=true)]` to `AccountTransaction.OrderLineId` to see if that will fix it. I'll edit my answer too.

Comment: I'm almost sure that 1:1 relation need to be direct through the key of both entities not with an additional property. Try to move the [Key] attribute to OrderLineId and change the type to int (because this value can not be nullable)

Comment: @Miguel Technically, he's wanting a 1:0..1 relationship here, not a true 1:1. Having a shared primary key would probably be better, but not knowing more about the actual structure here and not being certain that a 1:many relationship wouldn't be better, I'm not going to suggest schema changes. :)

Comment: @CptRobby I got you, he may need to use the Context Mappings directly for that. I don't think he can do it with attributes only.